# optimize sql select with many Joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join, optimization, query-optimization

How can I optimize this mysql statement?

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.name
FROM Something_Meta s1
JOIN Something_Meta s2 ON s1.fk_somethingId = s2.fk_somethingId
JOIN Products p ON s2.fk_productId = p.id
JOIN 
(
     select fk_id from Restricted where fk_foo != 233 and fk_id NOT IN 
        (
            Select fk_id  from Restricted where  fk_foo = 233 
        )

)
r ON r.fk_id = p.id
WHERE s1.fk_somethingId = 63 AND s2.fk_somethingId <> s1.fk_somethingId

order by p.name ASC
```

My tables are like that

`Product (id,name )`
`Restricted (id,fk_id,fk_foo )`
`Something_Meta (id,fk_id,fk_somethingId )`

fk_id is foreign key to product (id)

Probably that sql statement needs optimization..

```
 select fk_id from Restricted where fk_foo != 233 and fk_id NOT IN 
    (
        Select fk_id  from Restricted where  fk_foo = 233 
    )
```

The whole query statement needs more than 1.5 sec to run which are many secs for a website for a single query.

Comment: a little context would help, such as how many records are in Restricted

Comment: NOT IN is dangerous in case of nulls. Be forewarned

Comment: @Drew yep, thanks for your point, but all the cells are not null by definition. ;) I hope that solve the NOT IN problem. right?

Comment: yes, it is a case of [knowing your data](http://pastie.org/10575344#9), and many people don't

Comment: but we can't in good faith make recommendations for index changes without knowing your schema, and what other parts of your system we will bludgeon by saying try this index or that index. It's fun sleeping at night after typing stuff

Answer (score 0):

You could try an index on `(fk_foo, fk_id)` which would cover your entire query:

```
create index ix_restricted_fk_foo_fk_id(fk_foo, fk_id) on restricted
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but my question before was incomplete. Do you have any idea how to optimize or even implement that `create index` to my query?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with mysql; but wouldn't the index-field-order `fk_id`, `fk_foo` make more sense? You always go in with an equality on `fk_id`, but only once on `fk_foo`, the `fk_foo <> 233` probably will cause an index scan all over the index if said field is in front. Having `fk_id` in front should cause at least that part to seek; the remaining etnries on `fk_foo` should be 'a lot less'... (as always, it depends a lot on the data too)

Answer (score 0):

First off : the `DISTINCT` is a bit of a red flag. If you need to filter out the doubles then there's probably an error somewhere (either in the query or the design) causing the doubles.

Second; you could write your query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.name
FROM Something_Meta s1
JOIN Something_Meta s2 ON s1.fk_somethingId = s2.fk_somethingId
JOIN Products p ON s2.fk_productId = p.id

WHERE s1.fk_somethingId = 63 AND s2.fk_somethingId <> s1.fk_somethingId
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                   FROM Restricted r
                  WHERE r.fk_foo != 233 
                    AND r.fk_id  = p.id )
AND EXISTS ( SELECT *
               FROM Restricted r2
              WHERE r2.fk_foo = 233
                AND r2.fk_id = p.id )

order by p.name ASC
```

As I don't have a clue about the `Something_Meta` tables I'll simply focus on the `Restricted` table and suggest you put an index on fk_foo and fk_id. Said index is NOT part of the query, but rather of the table, so you have to define it upfront, once.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_Restricted ON Restricted (fk_id, fk_foo)
```

Once the index is there; any query that might benefit from it will automagically use it in the background; no need for you to adapt the query for it.

Side-note; since you obviously are looking for the product I find it curious you don't 'focus' your query on `Products`.

```
SELECT p.name
  FROM Products p
  JOIN etc...
```